Identify SMD voltage regulator with top marking: BDCM
I've a circuit powered by a regulator IC. The regulator is a SMD one, with this code on its surface: BDCM
The package SOT-23-6.

Unfortunately, I do not find any information about the BDCM marking code.
I need to know the pinout and range of incoming voltage.
Any hint about how to continue?

Thanks for the feedback guys! I took a closer look at the panel and circuit pinout as suggested by bobflux. Based on these, @nanash1 gets the point. This is a load switch. Unfortunately, it has failed. I will try to replace it with this type: AP22653.

The markings match with an ETA Solutions ETA6020S2G-T which is a load switch and not a regulator.

The markings with the underscore under the last character also points towards ETA Solutions. See the ETA1036V50S2F as example from this question, it has the marking CPYW:

(Source: lcsc.com)
I can't find a full datasheet, but here is a picture of the pin out:

(Source: www.gys.cn)

Thanks for your answer, very useful!


I don't know about the exact part number, but the pinout should be easy to find:
I assume there isn't an inductor on the other side of the board...
The dot is the Pin 1 marker. I see some caps on this pin, so it's either the input or the output.
Pin 3 connects to the midpoint of a voltage divider (resistors marked 3) so this is probably an adjustable voltage regulator. This means pin 1 is the output, since one of the resistors connects to it.
Pin 2 should be Ground since there is no visible connection, there's probably a via under the chip.
Capacitors on pin 6, so it's the input, you can check continuity to the upstream power source.
Pins 4 and 5 have resistors, which hints of a PGOOD output or ENABLE input, hard to say, you'd have to check if they are pullups or pulldowns. If it's a pullup to the input voltage, then it's most likely an ENABLE input. If it's to the output, then probably PGOOD.
There doesn't seem to be a noise reduction cap...
Unfortunately, being an adjustable regulator, the output voltage depends on the voltage reference setting, and to know what that is, we'd need the datasheet...
Downstream devices may provide more useful information about output voltage, for example if you see a chip that requires 3V3. As for input voltage, you'd have to look at the rest of the circuit.
Since the LDO package looks inflated, I assume it is dead. You may want to check if there is a short from input to output. If this is the case then whatever circuitry is downstream may have received the wrong voltage, potentially making the whole board not worth repairing. On the other hand, maybe only the LDO is dead. I'd recommend desoldering the LDO, getting an idea of what its output voltage should be by looking at the downstream circuitry, and powering it with a bench supply. If it works, then it would be worth it to spend time finding a new LDO with the same pinout...

Thanks for your answer.

From the marking code and package it might be a Ricoh R5421N132F Battery Management IC
Li-Ion, over-charge/discharge prot., Vd=3.2V
The Ricoh R5421N SERIES MARK SPECIFICATION shows the first two characters of the marking are BD with the final two characters as a lot number:

Found the datasheet which has the block diagram:

This is a different type of device than the other answers, but it does show with only a few characters for marking codes, the same marking code may be used by different manufacturers for devices which are not drop in replacements.

Thanks for your answer.
